# Why do we specify the System.Reflection.Missing.Value?

Tags: c#, sql, excel

xlWorkBook.SaveAs("C:\examples\employee.xls", Excel.XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, Excel.XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlExclusive, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue, misValue);

In the above relation why do we write most of the misvalue .
please explain,
Thanks in Advance

Comment: How is this related to C, C#, or SQL? It seems that the code you show is VBA. Please don't spam with unrelated tags. Also please take some time to read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: This question looks like valid C# to me.

Comment: @Polyfun Even with those backslashes in the string?

Answer (score 2):

You are calling a COM component (Excel) using COM interop. COM is a totally different (and older) framework to .Net. To help you call the COM component, .Net creates a [Runtime Callable Wrapper](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/native-interop/runtime-callable-wrapper) (RCW) which is a proxy class that allows you to use managed C# code to call COM. But C# and COM implementations of optional parameters are not compatible with each other--the C# compiler does not know how to map a default C# parameter onto a default COM parameter. Thus, for default COM parameters we have to explicitly give them the System.Reflection.Missing.Value.